# ASP.NET authorization, show browser login dialog

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization

I have such section in my web.config to deny access of anonymous users to elmah.axd. Is it possible to make exception and add credentials for admin user to allow that user access protected web page? I would like to display browser authentication dialog and ask user for credentials before accessing elmah.axd url.

```
  <location path="elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it.

http://www.xoc.net/works/tips/forms-authentication.asp

By the way browser authentication forms are usually used in intranets with Windows authentication. And not forms authentication.

Comment: I know how to add html form authentication. I am asking is it there any method to show Browser login form authentication.

Comment: Like I said the browser authentication form works for intranets. IE is integrated to a windows login. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx. No need to give me negative points when I disclosed the difference right from the beginning.

Comment: Try basic authentication. That will make the browser pop up  
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/mybasicauthentication.aspx

Answer (score -3):

Yes:
 Add this to `<system.web>`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms    name=".ASPXAUTH"
          loginUrl="Login.aspx"
          protection="All"
          timeout="30"
          path="/"
          requireSSL="false"
          slidingExpiration="true"
          defaultUrl="Login.aspx"
          cookieless="UseCookies"
          enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
</authentication>
```

It will redirect anonymous users to Login.aspx

Comment: I would like to show Browser Authentication form and not web page.

Comment: why do you emphasis on browser login?